Can I add Week column to the standard calendar table from the DAX patterns?
I'm learning about date table patterns in power bi from https://www.daxpatterns.com/patterns/
I really like the standard time related calculations approach wherein they are creating a calendar table for year, qtr, month. They have shown show to calculate YTD, YOY, etc. https://www.daxpatterns.com/standard-time-related-calculations/
I want to enhance this table to add 2 columns: Year week, Week. I'm not sure why they don't already have these columns.
My question is whether the above is OK to do, or do I need to use the table that they have shown in the week related calculations (https://www.daxpatterns.com/week-related-calculations/)?

If your analysis focuses on week-based calculations like for example you have some sales comparison by weeks), you can have benefits from the specific week-related patterns provided in the week-related calculations pattern from DAX Patterns.
However as a general use I think when you extend the standard calendar table as mentioned in the links can be enough.
If you want to add them in your DAX code :
   Calendar = 
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            CALENDAR (DATE(2024, 1, 1), DATE(2024, 12, 31)),
            "Year", YEAR([Date]),
            "Month", MONTH([Date]),
            "Quarter", "Q" & QUARTER([Date]),
            "YearMonth", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY-MM"),
            "DayOfWeek", WEEKDAY([Date]),
            "DayOfMonth", DAY([Date]),
            "WeekOfYear", WEEKNUM([Date], 2) 
        ),
        "YearWeek", YEAR([Date]) & "-" & FORMAT([WeekOfYear], "00"),
        "Week", WEEKNUM([Date], 2)
    )

If you ask about when to use Week-Related calculations tables, in my opinion at least from the cases that I encountered it is mainly when you need fiscal dates or when for example your weeks start on a day other than Monday.

But same week can fall in 2 months. How to handle this ?
